# Why is polymorphism useful in Java?

Tags: java, polymorphism

Why would we want to say `Base b=new Derived()` versus `Derived b=new Derived()`? As far as I know (correct me if I'm wrong) if we do the latter we could still add it to an `arrayList<Base>`, right?

Comment: So that the actual implementation class is only defined in one place, so you can change it without breaking everything. The 'in Java' part of your question is pointless. It's useful in all the languages that have it.

Comment: http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd_spring05/java/archives/0508/barnabee/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem I recently had to deal with.

Let's say I have a parent class `Enemy` with child classes `EnemyBlob` and `EnemyBat`. Now lets say I want to store all of the enemies in an ArrayList. If I try to do `ArrayList<EnemyBat>` then I'll need a seperate ArrayList for each type of Enemy.

However, if I use `ArrayList<Enemy>` then I can add both `EnemyBlob`'s and `EnemyBat`'s to it.

In addition, this lets you use different types of objects.

`ArrayList` is a subclass of `List`. If you define all the places you define a list as `ArrayList`s, then if you get a different type of `List` (for example to a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`) then you won't be able to use it.

Basically Polymorphism gives you flexibily to use and override classes.

Comment: the last sentence said it all

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference between these:

```
Base b = new Derived();
list.add(b);

// or

Derived b = new Derived();
list.add(b);
```

so use whichever you prefer.

There is a difference in other cases - here are some examples:

```
// this works fine
Base b;
if(randomNumber > 5)
    b = new Derived1();
else
    b = new Derived2();

// this does not compile
Derived1 b;
if(randomNumber > 5)
    b = new Derived1();
else
    b = new Derived2();

// this also works fine, but if you change Base to Derived1 it will not compile
void foo(Base b) {
    System.out.println("Type is "+b.getClass().getName());
}
void bar() {
    foo(new Derived1());
    foo(new Derived2());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, but declaring an array list as taking `Base` instead, will permit to store `Base`, `Derived` and all their child.

Comment: True, but why would you want to say Base b=new Derived(); arr.add(b); instead of Derived b=new Derived(); arr.add(b);?

Comment: Base b will have the opportunity to be used by methods and objects taking Base as parameter, while Derived b will be only usable by more specialized methods, taking Derived as parameter. In you case, it may not be useful, as you are only putting them in a list.